# com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: java.lang.IllegalStateException is thrown when seeking on Android on ReactNative

Tags: android, react-native, exoplayer, react-native-video

## Bug

I'm using `react-native-video` package for adding video player to my app. This error keeps getting thrown by react-native-video on Android. This happens when I play a video and seek it or sometimes when the video loads.

```
{"error": {"errorException": "com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: java.lang.IllegalStateException", "errorString": "ExoPlaybackException type : 1"}}
```

### Platform

`Android ReactNative Exoplayer`

### Environment info

`react-native info`

```sh
System:
    OS: macOS 11.4
    CPU: (8) x64 Apple M1
    Memory: 27.89 MB / 8.00 GB
    Shell: 5.8 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 14.17.0 - /usr/local/bin/node
    Yarn: Not Found
    npm: 7.19.1 - /usr/local/bin/npm
    Watchman: Not Found
  Managers:
    CocoaPods: 1.10.1 - /usr/local/bin/pod
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: iOS 14.5, DriverKit 20.4, macOS 11.3, tvOS 14.5, watchOS 7.4
    Android SDK:
      API Levels: 23, 28, 29, 30
      Build Tools: 28.0.3, 29.0.2, 29.0.3, 30.0.2, 30.0.3
      System Images: android-30 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom, android-30 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom
      Android NDK: Not Found
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: 4.2 AI-202.7660.26.42.7351085
    Xcode: 12.5.1/12E507 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  Languages:
    Java: 1.8.0_292 - /usr/bin/javac
    Python: 2.7.16 - /usr/bin/python
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
    react: 16.13.1 => 16.13.1 
    react-native: 0.63.3 => 0.63.3 
    react-native-macos: Not Found
  npmGlobalPackages:
    *react-native*: Not Found
```

`Library Version`

```json
react-native-video: 5.1.1
```

### Steps To Reproduce

`Exact steps to reproduce`

#### Way 01

1. Start playing in portrait mode.
2. Switch to landscape mode and seek to some random position.
3. Play the video.
4. Video buffers for sometime and then error is thrown. Video doesn't continue playing.

#### Way 02

1. Wrap the Video component in a small `View` as as follows:

```
<View style={{width: 200, height: 200}}>
...<Video/>
</View>
```

2. Error is thrown as soon as the video is loaded.

> `Note` In both the cases, I have set `controls={false}` and I was manually handling the seek, play, resume, etc.

### Expected behaviour

1. Error shouldn't be thrown when I seek and then resume playing it!

> `MORE INFO AND IMPLEMENTATION DETAILS ARE HERE`: [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/react-native-video/react-native-video/issues/2441) and [Implementation gist](https://gist.github.com/m-zaink/541b2b419d93ad58885731c17d81b6b1)

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?